# Debugging QuerySets in Django

Tags: django, django-models

When in debug mode and looking at a QuerySet that did return results, how / where can I see the objects in the debugger? I am not interested in the code to evaluate (e.g. `Class.objects.all()` etc, but more like the structure, e.g.:

```
- QuerySet
-- object_list
--- object[0]
--- object[1]
--- object[n]
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Let's say I am looking at a QuerySet in the debugger, I am getting a bunch of attributes and related objects, but I cannot seem to find the actual objects that I am after. If I have a class A and I am executing `qs = A.objects.get.all()` and I am looking at the structure of `qs` in the debugger, I am getting a bunch of different items but cannot find the actual objects / instances of A.

**EDIT(2):**
[image: debug screenshot]

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking

Comment: @JPG - ok, I edited... hope it is clearer now.

Comment: do you have a `PK` value or similar values of the target object?

Comment: aprt from that, I don't understand the context of `debugger`. Is it related to some specific IDE?

Comment: So, I am using PyCharm as an IDE. And when in debug mode, I can use the 'Evaluate' functionality (I guess same as / similar to the python console). When I execute / return a QuerySet, I can check the object of the same using `Class.objects.get.all()`. My question is now, where do I see all the objects? My point is that I don't have a PK or a uuid and I am expecting a list of all objects to see... I am adding a screenshot to the original post to highlight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated),

> Internally, a **QuerySet** can be constructed, filtered, sliced, and generally passed around without actually hitting the database. ***`No database activity actually occurs until you do something to evaluate the queryset`***.

Which means, wheever you call ***`Class.objects.all()`***, it won't **fetch the actual instances from DB** (just like `generators` in **Python**)

---

to evaluate all objects, do something like this,

```
all_instance = [i for i in Class.objects.all()]
```

The above method is not recomended for your production/live code, because it's too ugly to store all instance in a `list`

Comment: Nevertheless, it does fetch something while debugging, right? Shouldn't I be able to navigate to / display the individual object instance within the QuerySet?

Comment: @DevKing You can't debug a queryset by inspecting its objects. Bu if want to do, you can try my method

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the best way is to add to watches `list(Class.objects.all())`

Comment: Or just pop this in the debug console as needed